# Dichotomy in the number of regions on a plane formed by an infinite number of lines

Tags: geometry, limits, recurrence-relations, infinity, plane-curves

I'm reading Knuth's *Concrete Mathematics* and we are dealing with recurrence relations. He proves that the number of regions $L_n$ formed by $n$ lines on a plane is $L_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

I don't have the formal proof for it, but I have an intuition that an infinite number of lines in two dimensions forms a plane - because there are an infinite number of points that can live on these lines and therefore every single point in 2-D space lives on these lines and so we have a curve.

Under the tentative assumption that this postulate is true, I'm wondering what the behavior of $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} L_n$ is, i.e. how many regions are formed by an infinite number of lines on a plane.

A region is defined as a set of points not on the line segments that surround them. If with an infinite number of lines you cover the entire plane, i.e. the number of regions approaches $0$, but by the equation given the number of regions approaches $\infty$, there is a dichotomy. I'm not sure how to understand this or if I am missing something.

Comment: That formula is for the _maximum_ number of regions formed by $n$ lines on a plane, i.e. lines in a very special sort of arrangement. Why do you think that adding lines infinitely many times in that arrangement would cover the plane?

Comment: I think I understand your question. We are dealing with two ideas: (1) the maximum number of regions formed by n lines *in any arrangment* on a plane, and (2) the assumption that for an infinite number of lines on a plane, every single pair $(x,y)$ will live on those lines and therefore the entire plane will be covered, and therefore there will be no points **not** on the lines. Thus, I see 2 being true creating a contradiction on 1. *Is 2 false?*

Comment: I can give you an arrangement of infinitely many lines on a plane where not every point on the plane lies on a line: take one vertical line going through each integer point on the $x$-axis. If you want the lines in a bounded region, take one vertical line going through each point $(1/n,0)$.

Comment: thanks for explaining this to me. I'm going to change my question to be about lines in a bounded region.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an intuition that an infinite number of lines in two dimensions forms a plane - because there are an infinite number of points that can live on these lines and therefore every single point in 2-D space lives on these lines

It depends on how many lines you have. If you have a [countably infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) collection of lines, then you will have covered $0$ area no matter how you do it, and so there will be a lot of points missed. This is vaguely related to your correct idea that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}L_n=\infty$, though that limit only talks about the maximum numbers of regions for finite numbers of lines.

If you have [uncountably many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) lines, then it depends how you place them. For example, if they're all vertical and pass through points of [the Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) then you've missed infinitely many regions (in fact, countably infinitely many vertical strips). But if you place a vertical line at every horizontal coordinate, you'll cover your region completely.

This uncountable case is very far removed from $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}L_n$ since we're not talking about the limit of the number of regions of finitely many lines, or the countably many lines (which could be thought of as a "limit" of finitely many lines), but many more lines than that.

Answer (score 1):

A concrete example of infinitely many lines which dramatically fail to cover the plane: let $L$ be the collection of all lines of the form $y=mx+b$ with $m, b$ rational. Then as long as $\alpha\over\beta$ is irrational (and $\beta\not=0$), no line in $L$ will go through the point $(\alpha, \beta)$.

Let $A$ be the set of points not on some line in $L$. The (countably many) lines in $L$ divide $A$ into regions, each consisting of one point (exercise: if $p\not=q$ are distinct points in $A$, then there is a line in $L$ going between $p$ and $q$). However, even though there are *countably* many lines, there are *uncountably many* of these regions (that is, $A$ is uncountable)! This is the same sort of thing that's going on with the fact that the reals are uncountable, but have a countable dense subset (the rationals).

Bottom line: be careful about limits of infinite processes!